# R solving multiple linear systems where each RHS is a column of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, linear-algebra

I know I can solve the system `Lx = b` where `L` is upper-triangular using `backsolve` in R. However, now I have a matrix `B` where each column of `B` is a right hand side of `Lx = b`. Basically I want to solve `Lx = b` where `b` is every column of the matrix `B`. Is there a way of doing this more efficiently than just a loop?

I'm not posting a MWE because I'm pretty sure there should be a function to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try the following approach

```
x <- ginv(L)%*%b
```